# Unbinding a handler

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
function SOME_FUNCTION() 
{           
jQuery('.done').unbind('click').click(function(e) { 
// jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.done', function(e) {
...
success : function(data){                               
        alert('done');
        return false;
        }
    });         
  }
 // e.stopPropagation();
});     

}
```

So, the "`class="done"`" is loaded via ajax (new contents) and it looks like the handler is added to it multiple times. I tried "unbind", "off" etc, but I am still getting multiple alerts('done');

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to simply remove all the handler on this class? or only add the handler when clicked?

**EDIT:**

The `SOME_FUNCTION` function is called whenever ".button" is clicked.

```
function BUTTON_FUNCTION()
{           
// jQuery('.button').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
 jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.button', function(e) {                         
    ...
    success: function(data){                        
      SOME_FUNCTION();                                                          
    },          
});     
}
```

Comment: how many times you call  `SOME_FUNCTION()` ?

Comment: `success` is the handler for an AJAX request, not a click handler. Please include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), otherwise [this question is off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you use `on` on a parent element (in your case the document itself), then you don't need to unbind and re-bind. Just set the event handler once, and it will automatically apply to new elements added to the DOM.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you for the reply. As you can tell, I am bit new to js. Any examples? thanks

Comment: Just saying that you need to call `jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.done', function(e){...})` only once, no matter how early. Every element with the class `done` will trigger the given click event, even if it was added later after an AJAX request. The click event will bubbly up to the document at which point jQuery catches it and fires your click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the function just call this directly in your document ready function :

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.done', function(e) {
...
success : function(data){                               
        alert('done');
        return false;
        }
    });         
  }
});
```

all element with a class `.done` dynamically added or not will have only a single click event bind it to it

Comment: Yeah, I think i am going with this solution. I was making things too complicated. Thanks!

Comment: DRY principle at its best